# Is it possible to test capacitors on a logic board?

Tags: capacitor, multimeter, lcr

First, I would like to know if it is possible to test a capacitor while it is soldered to a logic board, or does it have to be unsoldered first?

Second, is it possible to do so with a multimeter?

Third, can [such an LCR meter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00N3UPLZ8) be used to test capacitors on a logic board?

[image]

Boards like these ones. The top one is the display logic board and the bottom one is the power supply:

[image: Boards like these ones]

Comment: Testing for what? Open? Short? Capacitive value? It will depend on what kind of circuit they're hooked up to as well.

Comment: @horta I have an LCD display that won't turn on anymore. I already changed all the capacitors of the power supply, and it is delivering proper power. On the display logic board, I changed the two capacitors that are more prone to go bad, but still the display won't turn on. I know it could be something else, but there is a bunch of other capacitors. If I wanted to test them to make sure they are good, would I have to unsolder them all?

Comment: @horta Since I need to find which capacitors need to be replaced, if any, from your comment, I guess the answer is no.

Comment: If it's delivering proper power, I'm not sure why you think capacitors would be the issue. Most of those caps are decoupling caps that just store energy. If you can power it on and see a correct voltage, then your decoupling caps probably aren't the issue. Without powering it on, you should be able to use a standard ohm-meter and watch the resistance climb from something small to eventually an open circuit. If it passes these two tests, you probably don't have a decoupling cap problem and instead a blown transistor somewhere.

Comment: @horta I meant the capacitor on the logic board (I hope I am using the proper term here), as opposed to the ones on the power supply board. Also, I might have spoken too rapidly when I said the PS was delivering proper proper power. It is delivering the correct voltage, but I don't know about the current.

Comment: Your logic board still has to have decoupling capacitors and power rails on it. Do you know if your backlight is bad or your lcd is bad? If it's a backlight only issue, you may have hope, but otherwise, I think you're in over your head.

Comment: @horta I don't think it is just the backlight. The LCD display does not power on, not even the LED on the power button. Also, there are three 5 Volts pins on the power supply. When the PS is disconnected from everything else, I measure 5 Volts on those pins. When I connect the logic board however, the voltage on those pins fluctuates between 0.6 Volts and 1.3 Volts. This is without the LCD and backlight being connected.

Comment: That seems like a short on your board somewhere and the power supply could be continually retrying to power things on but detects the short condition and restarts. A thermal camera or a special short detector would be necessary to find the short without unsoldering things one by one.

Comment: @horta You put a doubt on my mind about the PS delivering enough power. So I decided to connect something else to it and see. I connected an Arduino power supply to it. Ok, I cheated, the PS input should be between 6.5 V and 12 V (output can be either 3.3 V or 5 V). I did not connect anything to the Arduino PS, but there is a LED on it and the LCD display PS does note even manage to deliver enough power to the LED. Power is not constant, it is like a heart beat that faints. And I have changed all the capacitors on the power supply except for the really big one.

Comment: I'd check for shorts on them or unsolder them and check the capacitance. If it's the power supply, I'd bet it's a transistor failure. Check for shorts across any transistors you find. Replace any that show shorts with power off.